# possible to use rbenv with ruby2 to install ruby3?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-20.04, rbenv

I'm trying to get ruby3 on ubuntu20.04 (which I must use for policy compliance reasons) and only includes ruby up to 2.7

this version of ubuntu provides `rbenv`, and the list of available interpreters have `rbx-3.0`. When i try to install it i get

> bundler-1.3.6/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:240:in `dependency_api_uri': undefined method` encode' for URI:Module (NoMethodError)

not sure if the versions are related, but since the error i am getting (`undefined method` encode' for URI:Module`) is often caused by ruby 2 code running ruby 3, i'm guessing this is the source of my predicament.

Is there a work around for this? or a smarter way to go about getting ruby3 on this OS?

Comment: RBX is not standard Ruby. You likely want ruby-3.1.2, not rbx.

Comment: Rbenv includes ruby3 and you would install it exactly how you would any ruby2 version. Just make sure to update the rbenv versionlist. Also, make sure your version starts with 'ruby-3.x.x'. Rbx is an alternative interpreter.

Comment: Thanks both for the note about rbx. `renv` on ubuntu20.04 doesn't show ruby3. i would have to download it from the outside...